# Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку появлялся текст?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку появлялся текст ответа?

```js
const questionBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".question__btn")

questionBtn.forEach((element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    element.classList.toggle("question__btn--active")
  });
}))
```

```css
 .answer__text {
      display: none;
   }
```

```html
 <div class="question">
     <div>
         <p class="question__text"></p> 
         <p class="answer__text"></p>
      </div>
         <button class="question__btn"></button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Можете уточнить, какого поведения вы ожидаете при нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: Чтобы .answer__text становился display: block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.answer__text.active{
  display:block;
}

const questionBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".question__btn")

questionBtn.forEach((element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", () => {
  element.parentNode.querySelector('.answer__text').classList.toggle("active")
  });
}))
```